# Looping through sub-folders in a parent directory - vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to copy/paste data from workbooks within different sub-folders within a user selected directory.

To explain:  Basically, I want to automate a process whereby I perform a copy/paste ritual from many workbooks into one Summary Workbook (from which the code is initiated).
I have allowed user input to select the parent directory in which the subfolders are contained.

I have reached the stage where the looping occurs, but the data is not being copied and pasted.

Can anyone see flaw in my code or why it is not working?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub AAA()
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim FF As Scripting.Folder
Dim SubF As Scripting.Folder
Dim strFolderName As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        strFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
        MsgBox ("Selection Cancelled")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set FF = FSO.GetFolder(strFolderName)
For Each SubF In FF.SubFolders
    DoOneFolder SubF
Next SubF
End Sub

Sub DoOneFolder(FF As Scripting.Folder)
Dim F As Scripting.File
Dim SubF As Scripting.Folder
Dim WBc As Workbook
Dim shtWBc As Object
Set shtWBc = Sheets("QC Results")
Dim shtBatchwbk As Object
Dim lastrow As Long
Set shtBatchwbk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QC Results")
lastrow = shtBatchwbk.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

 For Each F In FF.Files
    If (F.Name) Like "QC_results*" & ".xlsm" Then
        Set WBc = Workbooks.Open(F)
    ' Copy QC results range into batch summary workbook
        shtWBc.Range("A4:SA11").Copy shtBatchwbk.Range("A" & lastrow)
        WBc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Debug.Print F.Name

    End If
Next F

For Each SubF In FF.SubFolders
    DoOneFolder SubF
Next SubF
End Sub
```

Comment: You have not asked a question. Is it working ? Then you should perhaps go on CodeReview. If it's not working then tell us what's not working.

Comment: Well, no it is not working. When the user selects the parent directory, nothing happens.  When the user selects a sub-folder as the parent, the first workbook opens and then it stops there... not copy/paste performed.  But then I presume it will not loop if I select the subfolder as parent....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
Sub DoOneFolder(FF As Scripting.Folder)
Dim F As Scripting.File
Dim SubF As Scripting.Folder
Dim WBc As Workbook
Dim shtWBc As Object
Set shtWBc = Sheets("QC Results")
Dim shtBatchwbk As Object
Dim lastrow As Long
Set shtBatchwbk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QC Results")
lastrow = shtBatchwbk.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

Notice that `shtWBc` and `shtBatchwbk` are most likely assigned to the *exact same worksheet object*.

`shtBatchwbk` is assigned from `ThisWorkbook`, and unless you have other workbooks open/active at the time, then `shtWBc` is assigned from the `ActiveWorkbook`, which would be the same workbook, thus the exact same worksheet.

The resolution would seem to be:

```
 For Each F In FF.Files
    If (F.Name) Like "QC_results*" & ".xlsm" Then
        Set WBc = Workbooks.Open(F)
        Set shtWBc = WBc.Sheets("QC Results")   '##### ASSIGN THIS WORKSHEET FROM THE NEWLY OPNEED WORKBOOk

    'Get the last row:
     lastrow = shtBatchwbk.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row


    ' Copy QC results range into batch summary workbook



        shtWBc.Range("A4:SA11").Copy shtBatchwbk.Range("A" & lastrow)
        WBc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Debug.Print F.Name

    End If
Next F
```

Otherwise, revise your Q to provide more detail per Alexandre's comment.

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

If you only need *values*, then this should be more reliable and faster than copy/paste.

Instead of:

```
shtWBc.Range("A4:SA11").Copy shtBatchwbk.Range("A" & lastrow)
```

Do this:

```
shtBatchwbk.Range("A" & lastrow).Resize( _
    shtWBc.Range("A4:SA11").Rows.Count, _
    shtWBc.Range("A4:SA11").Columns.Count).Value = shtWBc.Range("A4:SA11").Value
```

And if you also want to copy formatting without doing the full "copy" because it sometimes changes/transposes numbers, etc., then you can add this as well:

```
shtWBc.Range("A4:SA11").Copy
shtBatchwbk.Range("A" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: Thanks David.  You were right!  Copy and paste is now operating in the correct worksheet... But I need to fine tune the copy and paste code - it now pastes at fixes locations in the worksheet I.e. row 443 and row 444435.  I have only tested the code on with 2 loops, but I predict it will continue in this random manner.  Are there any suggestions to paste data sequentially below the previous copied data.  I only have experience with the line I have at present and it has been more or less faultless.

Comment: Move this line `lastrow = shtBatchwbk.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row` to be inside the `For each F in FF.Files` loop. This should redefine the `lastrow` value for each time you paste the data -- see my revised answer above.

Comment: Thanks David, That worked an absolute treat!! Having to validate the method code however, it seems that excel changes values during the copy paste method. :S  why, oh, why, oh, why does it do that!  I have been warned about this by a colleague... would cut/paste work better?  any explanations?  Again, many thanks David!

Comment: I've seen that happen before... it has been a while since I worked really in Excel and TBH I have not really tried to diagnose that, all I know is that sometimes Excel thinks it is smarter than the user, and will do things like this.  If copying *values* only is a suitable alternative, I can make another suggestion...

Comment: Mmmm... It was an error on my part.  Code is fine... Still will need some validation though.... Thinking of copying values too....  Suggestion? Should be straight forward I would think...

Comment: I made some additional comments above in my answer.  Try them and se if that works.

Comment: Thanks David.  It works well and quick! Copying formats was not necessary but thanks anyways. I decided to use the new suggestion above to validate the formulas... Seems like all is good to go.  Thanks for your help and patience!